# Changing the pay to account for PayPal mobile transactions

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using the latest PayPal 2.01 SDK for mobile transactions. I have 2 PayPal business accounts (sales1 and sales2) and based on the transaction I would like to choose which account the transaction is paid to.  I have a client ID for each account and want to choose which ID to use for the  [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction: ClientId] call. After I have initialized once, the next initialization is ignored and the client Id is not changed. Can someone tell me how to force the initialization to change the client Id.

```
    if (condition) {
        DLog(@"using PP Sales2 account");
        [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction:  kPayPalSales2Id,
                                                           PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: kPayPalTest2Id}];
    } else {
        DLog(@"using PP Sales account");
        [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction: kPayPalSalesId,
                                                           PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: kPayPalTestId}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

The scenario you describe, of switching `clientId` within a single session, is not one that we have designed the PayPal iOS SDK to handle.

Feel free to post this as an Enhancement request at [our github repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK).

Comment: Thanks Dave. I used to be able to indicate the PP account as part of the payment but now I cannot. Is there anyway to nullify the ClientId so the next initialize will not be bypassed?

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment switching `clientId` as you intend is not supported. Once the SDK has been initialized with the first `clientId` and `preconnectWithEnvironment:` has been called, then your session will remain associated with that first `clientId` regardless of any subsequent calls to `initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:`. But go ahead and post an Enhancement request at our repo, along with a short explanation of why you need this feature, and we will consider making the necessary changes.